# Yii2-user links to other pages not working correctly

Tags: yii2, yii2-user

I installed yii2-user. On the login view there are a couple links at the bottom of the form.

```
<?= Html::a(Yii::t('user', 'Didn\'t receive confirmation message?'), ['/user/registration/resend']) ?>
```

and

```
<?= Html::a(Yii::t('user', 'Didn\'t receive confirmation message?'), ['/user/registration/resend']) ?>
```

When I click either of these links the registration part of the url is taken out. So I'm left with a page not found. It will send me to

```
http://localhost/webs/parlay/web/index.php/user/resend
```

instead of sending me to

```
http://localhost/webs/parlay/web/index.php/user/registration/resend
```

heres my urlManager config.

```
'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        // Disable index.php
        'showScriptName' => true,
        // Disable r= routes
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this thread](https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/issues/351), perhaps you have old release of `yii2-user` package.

You can try remove `/` from `/user/registration/resend` or write custom rule like

`'user/resend' => 'user/registration/resend'`

Comment: I found something on this link you sent that helped

Answer (score 0):

added

```
<module:user>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>
```

to url manager. now working